# Is JBoss EAP 7.1 still spported?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

is JBoss EAP 7.1 still supported? 7.X is supported of course but what about the specific minor version 7.1? Are there still security updates?

I wasn't able to tell from the Website:
https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes/

Regards
stan

Comment: I would say no. 7.3 is the most recent 7 EAP. But why don't you ask RedHat?

Comment: So it says on the public website but within the JBoss access it says the maintenance stream shifted to the upper versions https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3824062